# How to properly include atlbase.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, openframeworks

I'm trying to work with some library code given to me that requires some of the ATL functionality but I consistently get errors like the following:

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\atlmfc\include\atltransactionmanager.h(396): error C2039: 'CreateFile' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\atlmfc\include\atltransactionmanager.h(427): error C2039: 'DeleteFile' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\atlmfc\include\atltransactionmanager.h(460): error C2039: 'MoveFile' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\atlmfc\include\atlbase.h(6517): error C2039: 'GetModuleFileName' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\atlmfc\include\atlbase.h(6517): error C3861: 'GetModuleFileName': identifier not found
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\atlmfc\include\atlbase.h(6591): error C2039: 'GetModuleFileName' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\atlmfc\include\atlbase.h(6591): error C3861: 'GetModuleFileName': identifier not found
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\atlmfc\include\statreg.h(481): error C3861: 'FindResource': identifier not found
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\atlmfc\include\statreg.h(674): error C3861: 'CreateFile': identifier not found
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\atlmfc\include\atlbase.h(6676): error C3861: 'GetModuleFileName': identifier not found
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\atlmfc\include\atlbase.h(6762): error C3861: 'GetModuleFileName': identifier not found
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\atlmfc\include\atlbase.h(6885): error C3861: 'GetModuleFileName': identifier not found
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\atlmfc\include\atlbase.h(7228): error C3861: 'GetModuleFileName': identifier not found
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\speech\v11.0\include\sphelper.h(1246): error C2039: 'LoadLibrary' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\speech\v11.0\include\sphelper.h(1246): error C3861: 'LoadLibrary': identifier not found
```

I do have it installed on my own machine and the original project itself compiles without problem. For confidentiality reasons I can't share the original project itself, but I can share its compile flags (apologies for poor formatting):

```
/Yc"stdafx.h" /GS /analyze- /W3 /wd"4995" /Zc:wchar_t /ZI /Gm /Od /Fd"Debug\vc110.pdb" /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "_USRDLL" /D "DLL_EXPORTS" /D "_WINDLL" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /Oy- /MDd /Fa"Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Debug\" /Fp"Debug\KinectCommonBridge.pch"
```

Here are mine (feel free to ignore the openFrameworks related includes, I'm trying to keep the project as close to their settings as possible so that it translates more easily for users):

```
/Yc"stdafx.h" /GS /TP /analyze- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /I"..\..\..\libs\openFrameworks" /I"..\..\..\libs\openFrameworks\graphics" /I"..\..\..\libs\openFrameworks\app" /I"..\..\..\libs\openFrameworks\sound" /I"..\..\..\libs\openFrameworks\utils" /I"..\..\..\libs\openFrameworks\communication" /I"..\..\..\libs\openFrameworks\video" /I"..\..\..\libs\openFrameworks\types" /I"..\..\..\libs\openFrameworks\math" /I"..\..\..\libs\openFrameworks\3d" /I"..\..\..\libs\openFrameworks\gl" /I"..\..\..\libs\openFrameworks\events" /I"..\..\..\libs\glut\include" /I"..\..\..\libs\rtAudio\include" /I"..\..\..\libs\quicktime\include" /I"..\..\..\libs\freetype\include" /I"..\..\..\libs\freetype\include\freetype2" /I"..\..\..\libs\freeImage\include" /I"..\..\..\libs\fmodex\include" /I"..\..\..\libs\videoInput\include" /I"..\..\..\libs\glew\include\" /I"..\..\..\libs\glu\include" /I"..\..\..\libs\tess2\include" /I"..\..\..\libs\cairo\include\cairo" /I"..\..\..\libs\poco\include" /I"..\..\..\libs\glfw\include" /I"..\..\..\libs\openssl\include" /I"..\..\..\addons" /I"src" /I"..\..\..\addons\ofxKinectCommonBridge\src" /I"..\..\..\addons\ofxKinectCommonBridge\libs\KinectCommonBridge\include" /I"..\..\..\addons\ofxGui\src" /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\atlmfc\include" /ZI /Gm /Od /Fd"obj\Debug\vc110.pdb" /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "POCO_STATIC" /D "CAIRO_WIN32_STATIC_BUILD" /D "DISABLE_SOME_FLOATING_POINT" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /Oy- /MDd /Fa"obj\Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"obj\Debug\" /Fp"obj\Debug\SpeechExample_debug.pch"
```

I'm not very familiar with the ATL or it's use but this seems to me that it shouldn't be that difficult to include this file properly. I've dug through both projects and I can't find anything fundamentally different in any of the includes or compiler flags. Thanks for any guidance and I'm happy to provide any more information if it's helpful.

Comment: These are identifiers that come from the Windows SDK header files.  Atlbase.h already knows how to #include windows.h so the real reason is difficult to guess at.  The specific names are ones that have different names in the winapi, having either an A or W appended.  W in your case since you compile with UNICODE in effect.  That is not happening, for some reason.  If you can't share anything then ask help from your colleagues or use a hired gun.

Comment: I have provided all the compiler flags. Without providing the actual project files themselves or all 1600 files in my project I'm unsure of what further information I could provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`::CreateFile` is defined in `WinBase.h`. So you should #include `WinBase.h` or `Windows.h` before you include **atlbase.h**.

I can't tell for sure why this is not done in **atlbase.h** itself. But you can define what Windows header files are used in your project.

Comment: I've happened to pass by this and would like to thank you sincerely for answering a question which although closed by the overly-pedantic "guardians" of SO, does seem to be a legitimate question given that it's been viewed 642 time despite being closed.